# How to get BNB token balance in metamask wallet in React?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, blockchain

This is snippet of my code.

```
    const getBalance = (userAddress: String) => {
    const provider = new Web3((window as any).web3.currentProvider);
    const bnbContract = new provider.eth.Contract(bnbTokenAbi, tokenAddress);
    bnbContract.methods.balanceOf(userAddress).call().then((res: any) => {
      setBalance(res);
    }).catch((err: any) => {
      console.log(err);
    });
  }
```

But only the catch function works, what's the reason?

Answer (score 0):

balanceof is used for any token but bnb or eth and all the main token of the chains
correct function is balance
address.balance

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).